# Github Tensorflow: Browsing by branch is different than browsing by tag?

Tags: git, tensorflow, github

The interested repo is [Tensorflow Model](https://github.com/tensorflow/models).

It baffles me in that browsing the repo by branch, e.g. `master` is different than browsing by tag, e.g. `v2.8.0`, in terms of content. For example, in the tag `v2.8.0`, folder `research` is missing.

[image]

[image]

I understand code and folder structure can be changed overtime but this missing is consistent also over other branches, e.g. `v2.7.1`. So it must be by-design from the beginning.

I'm not an expert on Git/GitHub. I wonder what is the reason for this discrepancy/difference (e.g. git submodule, but how can I detect submodule is being used?)?

**Ultimate goal**: I want to download the repo at a specific tag. I tried `https://github.com/tensorflow/models/archive/refs/tags/v2.8.0.zip`, but after extracting, the folder `research` is still missing.

Comment: Repository content may differ a lot between different branches. You should not expect content to correspond to current state of the master branch everywhere.

Comment: A Git *tag* is a name for one specific commit—just like a raw hash ID, except that raw hash IDs are unusable by humans (vs tags like "v2.8.0" which are human friendly). A Git *branch name* is also a name for one specific commit. The key difference between a branch name and a tag name is that the commit named by the branch name will change over time; the commit named by the tag name should stay the same forever. Hence a branch name means "the latest commit in the branch", while the tag means "this one specific commit, forever".

Comment: Each *commit* has whatever files it has: those commit contents can never be changed; that particular commit number means *that* commit, which has *those files*, forever. Each commit can have *entirely different* files (names, contents, etc.) from any and every other commit—but typically, commits "on a branch" evolve slowly from one commit to the next, rather than changing radically.

Comment: Since tag v2.8.0 means "that commit" forever, you don't have to worry about the contents changing if you get 2.8.0 now, vs if you get 2.8.0 next year or 100 years from now. But since branch name `bra` means "the latest commit", you can expect to get something slightly different tomorrow and very different 100 years from now.